# Screen wake up settings in power options or registry for windows OS?

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, screen

Is there any way I can wake up the screen after specified time? i found one option which can allow enable or disable or Important Wake times only. do we have any way we can specify the time for wake up of the screen.[image]ons

Any help Please. if any chance through powershell or any other scripting also fine.

```
{{powercfg.exe -change -monitor-timeout-dc 1
 powercfg.exe -change -monitor-timeout-ac 1
```

Like this i would like to make any change through powershell.

Comment: As you have no code and no specific language, I think this question is off-topic for [so] as it's not specifically about coding. It looks to be a more general question about Windows, so I think it would be better off on [su]. Voting to move.

Comment: @Jmaes C. This post is for if any chance in the powershell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell script to wake up the monitor on a specific time. Tested with Windows 10

```
$Signature = @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void mouse_event(Int32 dwFlags, Int32 dx, Int32 dy, Int32 dwData, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
"@

Try {
$ShowWindowAsync = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name "Win32ShowWindowAsync" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru -ErrorAction Ignore }
Catch { }

$MONITOR_ON = -1;
$MONITOR_OFF = 2;
$MONITOR_STANBY = 1;

[datetime]$WakeUpTime = "02-26-2019 09:40:00 PM" # Set your Wakeup time MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

[System.Int64]$MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;

[System.IntPtr]$HWND_BROADCAST = New-Object System.IntPtr(0xffff)
[System.UInt32]$WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112
[System.IntPtr]$SC_MONITORPOWER = New-Object System.IntPtr(0xF170)

$ShowWindowAsync::SendMessage($HWND_BROADCAST, $WM_SYSCOMMAND, $SC_MONITORPOWER, [System.IntPtr]$MONITOR_OFF);

$Wait = $true

While($Wait)
{
    If((Get-Date) -ge $WakeUpTime)
    {
        $ShowWindowAsync::mouse_event($MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 0, 1, 0, [System.UIntPtr]::Zero);
        $wait = $false
    }
}
```