# Using PowerShell to send space character to desktop - to wake screen from sleep

Tags: powershell

I know the following 2 line PowerShell script sends a space character to a new "shell" object it creates.
Which does bring my sleeping screen out of its slumber.
But that opens, momentarily, a PowerShell window.  So, if the screen is truly asleep-not a problem.

But, there are times of the day when this will run when the screen isn't in a sleeping slumber.  Hence, when that happens, the user sees a very short annoying flash of the created Wscript.Shell

I'd like to just send the space keystroke to the desktop - to wake the sleeping screen.  Without the momentary opening and closing of the Wscript.Shell
i.e., send the " " character to "the desktop" and not to a new shell object.
Is this possible?
I know nothing (obviously) about writing PowerShell.

```
$myshell=New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell" 
$myshell.sendkeys(" ")
```

Perhaps there is a way the PowerShell script could know if the screen and/or computer is not in a sleep state, and therefore this could all just be avoided from running in that situation?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How is the script being called?

Comment: powershell has a `-WindowStyle Hidden` argument

Answer (score 1):

This wakes the screen by mouse movement, not keyboard but seems to work for me.

Based on [Screen wake up settings in power options or registry for windows OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54866488/screen-wake-up-settings-in-power-options-or-registry-for-windows-os)

```
$Signature = @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, 
IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void mouse_event(Int32 dwFlags, Int32 dx, Int32 dy, Int32 dwData, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
"@

Try {
  $ShowWindowAsync = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name 
"Win32ShowWindowAsync" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru -ErrorAction Ignore }
Catch { }

$MONITOR_ON = -1;
$MONITOR_OFF = 2;
$MONITOR_STANBY = 1;

[System.Int64]$MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;

[System.IntPtr]$HWND_BROADCAST = New-Object System.IntPtr(0xffff)
[System.UInt32]$WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112
[System.IntPtr]$SC_MONITORPOWER = New-Object System.IntPtr(0xF170)

# this commands puts monitors to sleep
# $ShowWindowAsync::SendMessage($HWND_BROADCAST, $WM_SYSCOMMAND, $SC_MONITORPOWER, [System.IntPtr]$MONITOR_OFF);

# this command wakes monitors up
$ShowWindowAsync::mouse_event($MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 0, 1, 0, [System.UIntPtr]::Zero);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's being setup with a Powershell script to create a Task in task scheduler. That task then calls the 2 line PowerShell script to send the " " key, to wake the computer up just prior to the day's activity.

Comment: Comments containing a question on your question should be answered in the comments or by editing you question not as an answer to your original question

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. Since I am using AutoHotKey, the following code will use PowerShell to create a new task in task scheduler.  By using the **cmd /c start /min "" powershell ...** style of command, the pop-up window does not display - but the computer and screen wake up.

```
WakeUp:= A_Now
EnvAdd WakeUp, 10, Minutes       ; wake 10 minutes from now
UTC_Delta-= A_NowUTC, Seconds    ; Seconds is more accurate due to rounding issue
UTC_Delta:= Round(-UTC_Delta/60) ; Round to nearest minute to ensure accuracy
WakeUp   += UTC_Delta, Minutes   ; Apply offset to convert to UTC
FormatTime, WakeTime,% WakeUp, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"
psScript =
(
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute cmd -Argument '/c start /min "" powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command {$myshell=New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell" $myshell.sendkeys(" ")}'
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -WakeToRun
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At %WakeTime%
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName wakeup -Action $action -Settings $settings -Trigger $trigger -Force
)
RunWait PowerShell.exe -Command &{%psScript%} ,, hide
;use the following if you want to see PowerShell output
;Run PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command &{%psScript%}
```